# Is it possible for Selenium to open an Excel Workbook pragmatically

Tags: c#, selenium, appium

I have created a number of unit tests in C# and I run them using Selenium. I need to open a Workbook for a certain unit test. I'm wondering is it possible to pragmatically open a certain file using Selenium to do this. I have researched this however all the results are about web browsers.

Comment: You are using C# to run Selenium ... just use a C# library to deal with the Excel file. Selenium, etc. doesn't have to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for Selenium to open an Excel Workbook pragmatically

No.  As [their](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) site states:

> **Selenium automates browsers. That's it!** What you do with that power is entirely up to you.

If you want to automate Excel from a testing perspective, look into:

- *[Ranorex](https://www.ranorex.com/)* - (payware) high level record/playback; optional coding in c#
- *Office Tools for Visual Studio* - code your tests in c#; low-level
- *Ole Automation* in whatever language you like (that supports COM)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) Can Appium pragmatically open a WorkBook?

Comment: I don't know anything about Appium sadly